# Slow insert query

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I am currently investigating some really slow queries on my MySQL InnoDB DB.

Inserting around 30 records into different tables results in a response time of 13s and I am suspecting that something might be wrong with my indices etc.

This is an example of one of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `record_descriptions60 ` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `record_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `api_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `locale` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `record_descriptions60_record_id_locale_unique` (`record_id`,`locale`),
  CONSTRAINT `record_descriptions60_record_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`record_id`) REFERENCES `records` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I am trying to do a basic insert as per the log:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "insert into `record_descriptions60` (`description`, `status`, `source`, `api_name`, `comment`, `locale`, `record_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:10 [
      0 => "Some desc"
      1 => "approved"
      2 => "api"
      3 => "Some API"
      4 => "A comment."
      5 => "ENG"
      7 => 99
      8 => "2018-07-11 10:26:11"
      9 => "2018-07-11 10:26:11"
    ]
    "time" => 12.45
  ]
]
```

Any feedback on its structure? Any issues that you can notice?

Comment: You consider 30 inserts in 30 ms to be slow? How much faster do you think it should be? By the way, did you disable autocommit in your application?

Comment: Sorry @mustaccio, I was probably distracted when I was writing the time. The real one is *13s*, which is slow isn't it?

Comment: I would expect under 30ms for one row, even in the worst of situations; 13 _seconds_ is 'not possible'.  Something else is going on.  Look elsewhere; `INSERTs` do not take long.  Where did that "array:1..." come from?

Comment: @RickJames So, given the time from Laravel's Query log the above insert took 12.45ms which is fine I believe. So, e.g. 30 * ~13ms = 490ms = < 0.5s

I guess that suggests that the bottleneck is elsewhere and not in my mysql structure then ?

Comment: @thitami - Grrr... Then fix the question to say `13ms`, not `13s`.

Comment: @thitami - Huh?  I see only one row being inserted.  Where does 1.45 come from?  Is something 13 _seconds_?  _Please_ proofread.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry I did not make my self clear. The entire batch of inserts complete in ~13s. ~13ms (12.45ms to be precise) is the time that the above query needed.

Comment: @thitami - 30 rows inserted in 13 seconds _is_ unexpectedly long, even going into 30 different tables.  Please time each of the 30 `INSERTs`, then provide info about that one table.

Comment: @RickJames Each insert is taking approximately 13ms, so I suggest that something else is not quite right in my endpoint and not the DB queries.

The endpoint actually involves several nested loops.
Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12.45 *milliseconds* to `INSERT` one row is reasonable.  Here are some of the issues:

- All `UNIQUE` keys must be checked for this insert being a duplicate.
- InnoDB is crash-safe; this involves doing at least one disk write to assure it.  (This is one per "transaction"; by default each statement is a transaction.)
- Rule of Thumb:  10ms to do one disk I/O on a spinning (HDD) drive.
- So, 12.45ms *elapsed* time is realistic.

There are multiple ways to speed that up, and not take 0.5s for 30 inserts:

- "Batch" the inserts -- a single `INSERT` statement with many rows.
- `LOAD DATA`
- Put several `INSERTs` in a single transaction (`BEGIN...COMMIT`) so that that mandatory disk write is done only once for the batch.
- Turn off the write that I am talking about (trade speed vs security).
- Use multiple connections.
- SSDs are faster.
- Consider chucking the `AUTO_INCREMENT` and promoting the `UNIQUE` to `PRIMARY`.

With some combination of those, it is 'easy' to *average* 1ms per row.  Still, the *elapsed* time for one write (of several rows) is likely to continue to be more than 10ms.  That is, the *response* time, as opposed to the *throughput*, is not likely to get below 10ms.

Also, keep in mind that MySQL can be doing lots of other things (via other connections) at the same time.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed reply, @Rick James.

Apparently, my MySQL queries are not the major issue for the slow response times of my endpoint.
So I'll probably have to rethink my approach.